# Redis data structure design for sorting time-based values

Tags: database-design, redis

I'm performing some analysis on a data stream and publishing the results on a Redis channel. Consumers subscribe to these channels and get real-time data feeds. All historical data analysis results are lost.

Now I want to add the ability to store historical data in Redis so that consumers can query this historical data (mainly by time).  Since the analysis results are partitioned by time what would be the a good design to store the results in Redis?

Comment: Be wary that redis key-getting performance degrades linearly with the number of individual keys you're getting. So if you stored a large list of (mostly) contiguous data, it would take N times longer to fetch than a single-string representation of the timeseries of the data. (Not an issue for 300 values... but several orders of magnitude of added latency for 100k values).

Comment: @Nisan - I don't think I completely understand. Will the approach (using zsets below) will have this performance penalty if I'm storing date every 30 seconds.

Comment: Try populating a list the size you expect it to be and measuring how long it takes to read from it. Now try the same by saving the entire list as a string (for example, as a serialized JSON object, although there are certainly more compressed/performant options). In my experience, for very large lists (e.g. 50k-500k elements) of homogeneous data type (e.g. integers with at most K digits), it was about ~1000 times faster to store the entire list as the string representation of a timeseries and unpack it after reading from Redis.

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Sorted sets are `O(log(N)+M)`, and are not subject to the same time complexities of lists; they are far more efficient. @Nisan.H I don't agree with your suggestion, storing an entire list as a string might work for small lists, but does not scale to very large lists since it forces the client to retrieve the entire list and unpack it before performing any operations on it; this is not an efficient solution. The use of sorted sets outlined below is a text-book solution for the OP's question.

Comment: @Raffian While I agree in principle, it's been my experience that Redis takes about as long to read N values from a collection (list,set,sorted set,hashfield) as it does to read N regular key:value pairs. What doesn't take as long is reading a single very large value... This is very case specific and only an issue when your collections are very large AND your reads are large (many thousands of values per read operation), but it's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use redis [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set).

Sorted sets store data based on "scores", so in your case, just use a time stamp in millis; the data will be sorted automatically, allowing you to retrieve historical items using start/end date ranges, here's an example...

Add items to a sorted set...

```
zadd historical <timestamp> <dataValue>
```

..add some sample data..

```
 zadd historical 1 data1
 zadd historical 2 data2
 zadd historical 3 data3
 zadd historical 4 data4
 zadd historical 5 data5
 zadd historical 6 data6
 zadd historical 7 data7
```

..retrieve a subset of items using start/end range...

```
 zrangebyscore historical 2 5
```

..returns...

```
1) "data2"
2) "data3"
3) "data4"
4) "data5"
```

So, in your case, if you want to retrieve all historical items for the last day, just do this...

```
zrangebyscore historical <currentTimeInMillis - 86400000> <currentTimeInMillis>
```

Comment: What if two data inserts in the same milisecond?

Comment: While members are unique in a sorted set, scores (time stamps in this case) may be repeated.

Comment: you can add some random string before or after your data to keep it not repeated.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think in your last code example you'd want to reverse the range, i.e. `zrangebyscore historical <currentTimeInMillis - 86400000> <currentTimeInMillis>` since it looks like it expects the lower value first.

Comment: There's a detailed version of this concept here: https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/time-series/sorted-set-time-series/, though I don't understand, with the duplicate issue raised in the comments above, why we aren't doing `zadd historical 7 <timestamp>` instead. Seems like that'd work much better.