# API - Caching Pageable, Sortable and Searchable Database Results

Tags: c#, api, caching

Is there a best practice for caching database results that can be ordered, paged and searched on?

For example, would it be practical to cache, say:
**the second page of posts,

with a page length of 10,

a search query of "foo",

ordered by date descending?**

I am writing a web API in .NET Core, using MemoryCache for caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching data in application's memory has a few drawbacks like scalability.
When you have two instances of your application you find your self caching same data twice and it has cost of memory. And there will be some situation that data is in cache on one instance and not another.

Instead of using application memory, use something like Redis. It has some data structures like lists, sorted sets.

You can set a key as "pageNumber-searchQuery" and set result as value on redis.

Take a look at sorted sets :

https://redis.io/commands/zadd

[Redis data structure design for sorting time-based values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153154/redis-data-structure-design-for-sorting-time-based-values)

Comment: Thanks. And what about pageLength? Sorting could be handled after caching.